# Why force the user to use a secure password throught choosing the password for them to solve the password problem?

Tags: passwords

I have read in innumerables articles that „Passwords must die“, because they are blamed for being the cause of most cyber attacks. But why no just issue random generated passwords, with the added benefit that brute force and distributed brute force attacks. Throught sure they will be more likely to write it down or forget it, but we can just force or prompt they to use a password manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a single password problem but it has multiple aspects

### Passwords must be usable for the end user

So they are either chosen to be easy to remember (simple and easy to hack passwords) or a single more complex password is reused for multiple sites (password reuse).

**Your proposal somewhat addresses this problem** by basically giving the user no choice over the password, i.e. the user if forced to somehow deal with this. From the perspective of usability you replace on annoying thing (pick a password and remember it) with an even more annoying one: Unless the infrastructure is already there to deal with this (i.e. password management as software or on paper) the user is faced with a big hurdle to continue here. But even existing password management can be cumbersome to use - just try to explain all of this to elderly persons.

### Passwords are only a single factor of knowing something, which can easily be cloned

And cloning the password is basically what phishing attacks do, i.e. they try to trick the user into entering the password somewhere so that the attacker now knows the password and can impersonate the user. Password managers can help here a bit by offering to fill in the password only if the domain matches, but not all password managers do this and lists on paper don't either.

Also under pressure (as done offen within phishing attacks) users are eager to solve their problem and thus will also send the password by mail, tell it on the phone or enter it on random site even if the password manager does not offer to fill it in.

**Your proposal does not address this aspect at all.**

Comment: We can also prompt the user that if the password manager does no auto fill, then they are being scamed.

Comment: @Delfin: The core of your proposal was to make the server generate a secure password and not let the user pick one. You made no specific requirements to an ecosystem around this proposal, like the mandatory roll-out of password managers behaving in a specific way. I've explained the problems with such proposal. Now you start making requirements to the ecosystem, like a specific behavior of password managers. But once you introduce such requirements it might be worth to rethink the whole idea of passwords as an authentication factor - and thus make it even better. Like using public key crypto.